# Move selected checkboxes from one div to another. If unselect from the other div, it should reflect in the initial div

Tags: angular, checkbox

In one div i have populated the required check boxes.

Also i have managed to store the selected checkboxes to an object.

[image]

I wanted to know how to display this object (checkboxes) in another div. Also if i unselect from the other div it should also reflect in the initial div (two way binding).
The below code is used to populate the selected checkboxes.

```
selectedUsers(usrbysite: any, event: any) { //getting values of selected check boxes
    var index = this.checkeduserslist.indexOf(usrbysite);
    if (event.target.checked) {
        if (index === -1) {
            this.checkeduserslist.push(usrbysite);
            console.log('added', usrbysite);
        }
    }
    else {
        if (index !== -1) {
            this.checkeduserslist.splice(index, 1);
            console.log('removed', usrbysite);
        }
    }
    console.log('CHECKEDUSERSLIST :', this.checkeduserslist);
}
```

The below code is the initially populated div:

```
<div style="width:100%; height:120px; overflow-x: auto;">
<div *ngFor="let usersbysite of usersbysite" style="display:inline">
      <input type="checkbox"
          name="usersbysite"
          value="usersbysite.user"
          (change)="selectedUsers(usersbysite, $event)" />
           {{usersbysite.username}}
</div></div>
```

I want to populate in another div the object named **selecteduserlist**
 .

**Update**:
In Below shown image i have populated the check boxes. When i click on any of these checkboxes, it should go to the box above. Also when i uncheck from the above box, it should removed from above box and also its corresponding value in the below box should be unchecked.
[image]

Comment: What is the problem? And it's a bit unclear what you want exactly. Do you want to have checkboxes in the other div as well? Could you perhaps explain the usecase for this, because I'm having trouble understanding what this is for.

Comment: @AJT_82 Please see the edit sir.

Comment: Basically i wanted to know whether the selected checkboxes can be displayed on the upper box using ngModel so that the check/uncheck events are affected each other.

Comment: Okay, now I think I understand what you want! :) I will surely take a look at your code in a moment. Just now I'm in the middle of another coding issue :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would introduce a new property to your array... let's call it `checked`. This makes your life a bit easier. You can create it when you get your array, or you can add it on the fly, like we have here. So, populating the array like you have looks good to me, so I we won't touch it at all.

The other array is displayed like the following, where we have all checkboxes checked as default:

```html
<div *ngFor="let usr of checkeduserslist" style="display:inline">
  <input type="checkbox" (change)="remove(usr)" [checked]="true"/> {{usr.username}}
</div>
```

The change event would then remove that user from the array and also uncheck the checkbox in the other array:

```ts
remove(user) {
  let index = this.checkeduserslist.indexOf(user);
  this.checkeduserslist.splice(index, 1);
  // find the unchecked user from other array and uncheck the checkbox
  let resetUser = this.usersbysite.find(x => x.userid == user.userid)
  resetUser.checked = false;
}
```

The box get's unchecked, because we added to following line to the first array (with all users) with our new property `checked`.

```ts
[checked]="usersbysite.checked"
```

**[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/H3toY0nJz5kOVVJ4676f?p=preview)**

Comment: @AJ_82 Thank you very much sir...got it.

Comment: You are very much welcome, glad I could help! Have a nice day and happy coding! :)